# Converting UTC time to local time or EU daylight comparision

Tags: sql, t-sql

`Select   a, b, c, FROM x 
JOIN y ON x.x=y.x 
AND x.PlannedDateTime BETWEEN y.FromDateTime and y.ToDateTime`

`Plannedsate` time is local time  ( e.g. 2018-03-07 14:03:00.000)

`FromDateTime` is UTC  (2018-03-07 14:03:00.000 +01:00) I dont know UTC or daylight in EU
`ToDateTime`  is UTC (2018-03-07 15:27:00.000 +01:00)   I dont know UTC or daylight in EU

When I join on these dates as above written query I miss many records. I think due to different time format.

Please provide any solution thanks in advance

Comment: There's no `EU Daylight`. There are a *lot* of timezones and each country has its own daylight rules. In SQL Server 2016 and later you can use [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to speficy the timezone you want to target. In earlier versions you need to use the `datetimeoffset` type and switch from one offset to another with [SWITCHOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/switchoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: https://www.timetemperature.com/europe/europe_daylight_saving_time.shtml

Comment: 2018-03-07 14:03:00  is  the local time. (UTC + 1)

Comment: With this format, the time you see is the clock time, i.e. what a person looking at a clock would see, the UTC+1 is telling you the clock time is 1 hour ahead of UTC. There is no information about daylight saving time in the date you have.

Comment: Simply how do i convert  2018-03-07 14:03:00.000 +01:00 into local date time

Comment: how to convert  GMT time zone convert into local timezone?

Comment: Use AT TIME ZONE

Comment: can u send me exmaple Rikalous

Comment: `2018-03-07 14:03:00.000 +01:00` must be stored as [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which is the only data type in SQL Server that is time-zone aware. However, it is **not** daylight saving aware - but what is the data type of `Plannedsate`?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the comments, in SQL Server 2016 or later, you should use [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to convert a datetimeoffset to a specific timezone. To convert a datetimeoffset to the local time zone of the server, you first have to find it and then you can use it like this:

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation', 'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone

DECLARE @x DATETIMEOFFSET='2018-03-07 14:03:00.000 +01:00'
SELECT @x AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone

DECLARE @y DATETIMEOFFSET='2018-04-07 14:03:00.000 +01:00'
SELECT @y AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone
```

On my computer (located in Bucharest, Romania, which is also part of the European Union) the above query returns:

```
GTB Standard Time
2018-03-07 15:03:00.0000000 +02:00
2018-04-07 16:03:00.0000000 +03:00
```

As you can see, this takes into account the daylight savings time which would be in effect or not at the specified date.

Instead of the timezone of the server (or if you cannot use `xp_regread` due to permission issues), you may want to use a specific timezone, for example `'Central Europe Standard Time'`.